# Change rules for spacing in formulas

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, plain-tex

The following note is given in Donald Knuth 's TeXbook (page 170):
[image]
How can I change these rules? More specifically, I am interested in changing the `Punct` line from `(1) (1) * (1) ...` to `1 1 * 1 ...`.

In  TeXbook said (I don 't remember exactly where in the book this statement is located) that any rule of the plain TeX can be changed and, therefore, there is hope that the answer to my question exists.

Comment: These rules are hardwired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all versions of TeX other than Luatex these rules may not be changed.

In luatex each entry of the table corresponds to a command which allows the parameter to be set (as `\muskip` values)

```
\Umathordordspacing
\Umathordopspacing
\Umathordbinspacing
\Umathordrelspacing
\Umathordopenspacing
\Umathordclosespacing
\Umathordpunctspacing
\Umathordinnerspacing
\Umathopordspacing
\Umathopopspacing
\Umathopbinspacing
\Umathoprelspacing
\Umathopopenspacing
\Umathopclosespacing
\Umathoppunctspacing
\Umathopinnerspacing
\Umathbinordspacing
\Umathbinopspacing
\Umathbinbinspacing
\Umathbinrelspacing
\Umathbinopenspacing
\Umathbinclosespacing
\Umathbinpunctspacing
\Umathbininnerspacing
\Umathrelordspacing
\Umathrelopspacing
\Umathrelbinspacing
\Umathrelrelspacing
\Umathrelopenspacing
\Umathrelclosespacing
\Umathrelpunctspacing
\Umathrelinnerspacing
\Umathopenordspacing
\Umathopenopspacing
\Umathopenbinspacing
\Umathopenrelspacing
\Umathopenopenspacing
\Umathopenclosespacing
\Umathopenpunctspacing
\Umathopeninnerspacing
\Umathcloseordspacing
\Umathcloseopspacing
\Umathclosebinspacing
\Umathcloserelspacing
\Umathcloseopenspacing
\Umathcloseclosespacing
\Umathclosepunctspacing
\Umathcloseinnerspacing
\Umathpunctordspacing
\Umathpunctopspacing
\Umathpunctbinspacing
\Umathpunctrelspacing
\Umathpunctopenspacing
\Umathpunctclosespacing
\Umathpunctpunctspacing
\Umathpunctinnerspacing
\Umathinnerordspacing
\Umathinneropspacing
\Umathinnerbinspacing
\Umathinnerrelspacing
\Umathinneropenspacing
\Umathinnerclosespacing
\Umathinnerpunctspacing
\Umathinnerinnerspacing
```

The default values are specified as in the table from the TeXBook that you show but can be changed with

```
\Umathopordspacing\displaystyle=4mu plus 2mu
```

See section 7.5.2 of the luatex manual

Comment: Please tell how to change these rules in LuaTeX.

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov I already gave an example how to change the spacing between mathop and mathord in the answer

Comment: I apologize. I sent a comment after you updated the response and before I had time to see this update.

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov no problem, the timing on when you get alerted to other people making updates can be a bit strange sometimes:-)

Comment: Please tell where I can find what are equal to `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)`.

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov this is documented in the texbook in the paragraph that you show in your question eg an entry of 3 means the default is  `\thickmuskip` and (3) means it is 0pt in scrriptstyle, in luatex as you set the value for each style separately that means there are really 4*64 settings one for each of the parameters, in each of display, text script and scriptscript styles

Comment: Thanks! It just seemed to me that in the script style `(3)` does not mean `0`, but something less than `\thickmuskip`.

Comment: no (as you can check with `\showlists` or `\showoutput` no additional space is added in the () cases